# BackgroundTransferService Ram Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have some doubt about BackgroundTransferRequest RAM efficiency, or more probably, I'm missing something.

BackgroundTransferRequest should initialize a web request (GET by default) and then store the response to IsolatedStorage specified by DownloadLocation, so we shouldn't have any stream opened containing the result, we just have the physical file in the IsolatedStorage.

Simple, Easy, Efficient.

Then, why after 200 succeeded Downloads I still have 42k occupied ram?

Of course If I restart the application I have 1k occupied ram and previously downloaded files are still on the Isolated Storage, so we probably have something on the BackgroundTransferRequest that occupies ram and never free it, despite the dispose call.

Please correct me If I'm doing something wrong.

Below you can see the code snippet used for adding and removing transfers.

**INITIALIZING TRANSFER**

```
                BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transfer.TransferUri);
                transfer.RequestId = transferRequest.RequestId;
                transferRequest.DownloadLocation = transfer.DestinationUri;
                transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
                BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
```

**ONCE DONE, REMOVE TRANSFER**

```
                 BackgroundTransferRequest transferToRemove = BackgroundTransferService.Find(transferID);
                if (transferToRemove != null)
                {
                    BackgroundTransferService.Remove(transferToRemove);
                    transferToRemove.Dispose();
                    transferToRemove = null;
                }
```

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Do you still have 42K used after garbage collection has run?  Dispose != GC.

Comment: isn't GC handled automatically by c#? see that performance analysis http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/36/captureupk.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the BackgroundTransferService class you have to be very careful with references to the BackgroundTransferRequest objects to avoid memory leaks.

```
_BackgroundRequests = BackgroundTransferService.Requests;
```

The previous assignment will create new references to the BackgroundTransferRequest objects, thus you should always dispose of the existing ones to avoid memory leaks.

If in your code you keep a local reference to the BackgroundTransferService.Requests list, then you should always dispose of the old references when using the Requests property.

```
foreach(var Request in _BackgroundRequests)
{
    Request.Dispose();
}

_BackgroundRequests = BackgroundTransferService.Requests;
```

Since the BackgroundTransferService allows a maximum of 5 BackgroundTransferRequest objects to be queued, one can be tempted to use the Count() method on the BackgroundTransferService.Requests list.

Remember that this will create new references and can cause memory leaks. The best solution would be to keep an internal counter of the current queued transfers or to never care about the number of queued transfer and handle the exception thrown by the service when too many requests are queued.

Finally, one should dispose of the BackgroundTransferRequest objects once they have been completed (successfully or not), but you already do so.

Comment: By adding some more dispose somewhere and by this hint up here, I could stabilize the memory consuming, now it stopped to increase randomly